# Prove by induction $1 + z + z^2 + .... +z^n = \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}$ for $z \neq$ 1

Tags: complex-analysis

Prove $$1 + z + z^2 \ldots +z^n = \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1} \quad \text{ where } z\ne 1 $$

So I started to prove this by induction.
What have I done so far:

Let $n= 1$

$$1+ z + z^2 \ldots+z^n = \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1} \\
1+z \stackrel {?}{=}\frac{z^{2}-1}{z-1} \\~\\
1+z \stackrel {?}{=} \frac{(z+1)(z-1)}{z-1} \\
1+ z \stackrel{?}{=} z+1 \quad \checkmark$$

But I think this is wrong? And I don't know what to do next
and how to do it? But for **(a)** and **(b)** use
$e^{i\theta}$ and go from there. Or is this proof an assumption?

**Actual question:**

> Prove that if $z \ne 1$, then
> $$
> 1+z +z^{2}+\cdots+z^{n}=\frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}
> $$
> Use this result and De Moivre's formula to establish the
> following identities.
>
> **(a)** $1+ \cos \theta+\cos 2 \theta+\cdots+\cos n\theta=\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{\sin\left[\left(n+\frac{1}{2}\right) \theta\right]}{2 \sin (\theta / 2)}$
>
> **(b)** $\sin \theta+ \sin 2 \theta+\cdots+\sin n
> \theta=\dfrac{\sin (n \theta / 2) \sin ((n+1) \theta / 2)}{sin (\theta / 2)}$,
> where $0<\theta<2 \pi$.

Comment: Hence of cancelling result $1+z=z+1$

Comment: I really doub that (a) is true

Comment: Also, why so you repeatedly use `$...$` ? It's pointless to use them again and again.

Comment: @UmbQbify-Key20- why do you doubt that (a) is true?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose, because as far as I remember the summation for that was something same as that of sine but had only one term of cosine

Comment: I believe I did something wrong 
when n = 1 
should it be z not 1 + z? Now I am overthinking.

Comment: No, your post is completely fine.

Comment: because n = 1 , I will use 1 for n = 2 it shall be 1 + z

Comment: For ${n=1}$, it's ${1 + z}$... in the formula, it is ${1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^n}$, with ${n=1}$ you get ${1 + z}$

Answer (score 4):

This is provable using standard algebra; however, if you wish to do this by induction:

For ${n=1}$, we get ${1 + z = \frac{z^2-1}{z-1}=z+1}$, so it works. Now assume

$${1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^k = \frac{z^{k+1}-1}{z-1}}$$

This would imply that

$${1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^{k} + z^{k+1} = \frac{z^{k+1}-1}{z-1} + z^{k+1}}$$

Now we simplify the right hand side

$${=\frac{z^{k+1}-1}{z-1} + \frac{z^{k+1}(z-1)}{z-1} = \frac{z^{k+2}-1}{z-1}}$$

Altogether that's

$${1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^k + z^{k+1} = \frac{z^{k+2}-1}{z-1}}$$

which is the correct formula. And so we have shown that if it works for ${n=k}$, that would imply it works for ${n=k+1}$. We have shown it works for ${n=1}$, and so it works for ${n=2}$ then ${n=3}$... so by the Principle of Mathematical Induction,

$${1 + z + z^2 + z^3 + ... + z^{n} = \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}}$$

as required.

---

**Algebra proof**

Thought I'd add the Algebra proof because why not.

Define

$${S_n = 1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^n}$$

Then you see this is

$${= 1 + z(1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^{n-1})}$$

But

$${1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^{n-1} = (1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^n)-z^n = S_n-z^n}$$

So we get overall

$${S_n = 1 + z(S_n - z^n)}$$

We can now rearrange for ${S_n}$;

$${\Rightarrow S_n(1-z) = 1-z^{n+1}}$$

And so

$${S_n = \frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}}$$

This *looks* different from your form, but it's the same since we just multiplied by ${\frac{-1}{-1}}$:

$${\Rightarrow S_n = \frac{1-z^{n+1}}{1-z}\times \frac{-1}{-1} = \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}}$$

And so

$${1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^n = \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}}$$

---

**Part (a) and (b)**

Indeed for part (a) and (b) you want to use the fact that

$${(e^{i\theta})^{n} = e^{in\theta} = \cos(n\theta) + i\sin(n\theta)}$$

After applying this formula with ${z=e^{i\theta}}$, you want to equate both real and imaginary parts on the left and right hand sides of the formula. Can you take it from here?

Comment: (Really, any proof will use induction.)

Comment: this might sound an silly question LHS and RHS you added $z^{k+1}$ to be balanced right? 

but can we say this is true for why z can't be 1 cause you can't divided by zero?

Comment: @EM4 (1) Indeed correct :) We just added ${z^{k+1}}$ on **both sides**. (2) This is also correct yes, we can only divide by ${z-1}$ if ${z\neq 1}$

Comment: @ElliotG indeed, induction is much less to write. I have edited to include the algebraic proof also

Comment: for algebra proof how you got minus $z^n$ ?

Comment: for Mathematical Induction the steps are always n = 0 , n = k , n = k+1 ?

Comment: @EM4 We had ${1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^n = 1 + z(1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^{n-1})}$. You can see that ${1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^{n-1} = (1 + z + z^2 + ... + z^{n-1} + z^n) - z^n}$. I have added a ${z^{n}}$ and then subtracted it again so that the result stays the same

Comment: @EM4 not always, no. We can start at any point, for example I could start from ${n=2}$. **But that would only prove that the formula works for ${n\geq 2}$**. The ${n=k}$ and ${n=k+1}$ part is pretty much always the same though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111289/discussion-between-em4-and-riemannspointynose).

Answer (score 2):

So you have done the “base case” right, but it is easier to start from $n=0$ and then you have $1 = (z - 1)/(z-1)$ which is obviously correct for all $z \ne 1$.

For the “inductive step” you want to start from the assumption that this is true for some $n$ and prove the corresponding function for $n+1$ from that assumption. So you have that
$$
1 + \dots + z^n = \frac{z^{n+1}-1}{z-1}
$$
as a given assumption and you want to prove that if you add $z^{n+1}$ to both sides that you get $(z^{n+2} - 1)/(z-1)$ on the right-hand side.

This is very easy to do by writing $z^{n+1}$ as $(z^{n+2} - z^{n+1})/(z-1)$ and then adding the numerators, again making use of the assumption that $z \ne 1$.

Indeed the second part is I think to substitute in $e^{i\theta}$ and then take either the real or imaginary part of the resulting expression to get the correct sums on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

You should start from what you know, not from what you want to prove.  For $n=1$ you can say $1+z=1+z\cdot \frac {z-1}{z-1}=\frac{z^2-1}{z-1}$.  For the inductive step, see Riemann'sPointyNose's answer

Answer (score 0):

In formula
$$a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}=(a-b)(a^{n} + ba^{n-1}+ ... + b^{n})$$
put $z=a, b=1$. For formula itself you can use induction, or simply open brackets.